# Executing SQL query stored in an excel cell and then transfer the result set into a .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

> I have a SQL query stored in one of my excel sheet cells that I execute using the below VBA Code:

```
Sub run()

Dim dtStart As Date
Dim dtEnd As Date

Dim MRC As Variant

'Get the SQL text(s)
    MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value & ""




    'Check for UNDF queries
    If MRC = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Query has not yet been defined, please make a new selection")
        Exit Sub
    Else

    End If


'Set up query


Application.StatusBar = "Data Refresh: 1 of 1 "

'Update subTabs

     Sheets("Summary").Select
                With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("connection1").OLEDBConnection
                    .CommandText = MRC
                    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("connection1").Refresh


End Sub
```

> In addition to the above VBA code, I also have another VBA code that executes the different SQL view and transfers the SQL view result-set to a .txt file and saves it into a specific folder. Please see below for that code

```
Sub TEXT()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strCon, strSQL As String

strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
         "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" & _
         "Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=VRSQLADHOC;" & _
         "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
         "Auto Translate=True;" & _
         "Packet Size=4096;" & _
         "Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
         "Tag with column collation when possible=False"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1" 'Sql Query

Folder = "U:\"  'Path in U drive
Filename = "file_name_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".txt"  'Name of Text document
fpath = Folder & Filename

cn.Open strCon
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open strSQL

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set A = fs.CreateTextFile(fpath)
A.Write (rs.GetString(adClipString, , , vbCrLf, ""))

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

MsgBox ("file name " + fpath)


End Sub
```

> Currently I am interested in applying the second VBA logic of transferring the result-set data into .txt file to my first VBA logic, which takes care of executing the SQL query stored in one of the excel sheet cells.
>
> **To put it shortly I want to execute a SQL query stored in an excel cell and then transfer the result set into a .txt file**

Comment: It looks like all necessary code is here, is there an error or unexpected behavior?  `MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value & ""` in place of `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1" 'Sql Query`  ?

Comment: @JimmySmith just updated the 1st VBA code. So please see it again. Thanks

Comment: @JimmySmith It is not unexpected behaviour, I am just trying to execute the query stored in an excel cell using MRC = "" & Worksheets("SQL Text") instead of regular approach of strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this right, both these subs use really different ways do query the database.

In the first example you've got a db connection in a sheet, and you're using a cell to update that connection.
In the second, you've got a vba /adodb connection to the database. If all you want to do is refer to a cell in excel for the query, then simply change the line:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1" 'Sql Query
```

to something more like:

```
strSQL = Worksheets("SQL Text").Range("D4").Value
```